# Multiple images is not uploaded correctly saying The file "image.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error

Tags: javascript, laravel-4, laravel-5

This is my view to upload the image....

```
<div id="addmore1">
    <table border="0" border-spacing="5em" >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td> {{Form::label('Image')}}</td>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <Input type="file" name="image1" required>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="width: 80px; height: 20px">
                <td colspan="6"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
{{ Form::hidden('idevent', $event->idevent) }}
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" onclick="addmore1()" value="Add" 
                       style="background-color: #298537" />
                (limit=4)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height:20px;">
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='7'>
                <input class="btn btn-info pull-right" name="submit" 
                       type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" 
                       style="color: #080808;" /> &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And this is my addmore script....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 1;
    function addmore1()
    {
        if(i<=3)
        {
            i++;
            var div = document.createElement('div');
            div.innerHTML ='<td>Image:</td> <td colspan="5">' 
                          + '<Input type="file" name="image' + i + '"'
                          + ' required></td> </tr> </tbody> </table>' 
                          + ' <tr><td colspan="7"> <hr></td></tr>' 
                          + '<input type="button" onclick="'
                          + 'removemore1(this)" value="Remove"' 
                          + 'style="background-color: #c4291e"/>';
            document.getElementById('addmore1').appendChild(div);
        }
    }

</script>
```

I just don't get it what i am doing wrong. It gives me the error The file "image.jpg" was not uploaded due to an unknown error. But it works fine if it is a single query. I mean if i don't use the addmore script. Any help will be appreciated........

Comment: I formatted your code, it's now very much clearer than how it was. Please keep in mind writing clean and easy-to-read code